# Google Tag Manager + Analytics doesn't seem to be working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I recently set up Tag Manager and Google Analytics.

In Google Analytics

- I set up an account

In Tag Manager

- I pasted the Tag Manager script just under the body tag of all my pages
- I set up a container
- I added the "Universal Analytics" tag
- I copied my Google Analytics tracking ID "UA-...." to the tag
- I added the "All pages" rule to the tag
- I published the tag

When I hit one of my web pages, I see 
 - a call to googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-... (with my tag ID)
 - a call to google-analytics.com/analytics.js
 - a call to google-analytics.com/collect?...tid=UI-...&tgm=GTM-... (with both my tag and analytics ID)

Now when I go to the Google Analytics dashboard, I see no sessions, not even in the Real-Time  session dashboard.

Under Admin > Property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code, it says "Status: Tracking Not Installed" I assume this is ok since I didn't copy the Analytics script to my page, but the Tag Manager script instead.

Is there some delay, or am I setting it up wrong?

Comment: There is usually a delay for standard reports to be updated, and this happens typically within 24 hours. Are you checking that you are not filtering your own visits? Your steps look fine though. Usually you will see that tracking status message if you just installed the tracking code on your webpage.

Comment: I should note that when I copy-paste the google analytics script to one of my pages, the session appears immediately on my Analytics dashboard... unfortunately Analytics through Google Tag Manager still isn't working for me :(

Comment: Odd thing happened. After I pasted the Analytics code to one page, now all my pages (with just Tag Manager code) are being tracked by Analytics now. Maybe I had to trigger a startup in Analytics by copying its code specifically?

Comment: Odd indeed. The GTM tracking code isn't triggered by the GA code. Can you post images of your tag config?

Comment: My guess is maybe it was slow to track as you initially suggested since it tracked some earlier sessions before I copied the GA code to one of my pages.

Comment: ON eCommerce settings by going to Account settings.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend every time you sent up GTM with a analytics tracking tag that you check that it sends data. This can be done by looking at the developer tools with chrome or firefox. Really any web browser.

In your web browser open up developer tools and open network. Find the filter button a and search for "UA-".

If you see something that says pageview, scroll down the headers and you will see your UA Account number and if you used GTM to implement the tag you should see your GTM tag ID.

Reload the page and check again. If you see it means it is sending data to the correct property. If it is not then there is something wrong with your implementation.

If you set everything up correctly and still dont see data check your filters. I always recommend keeping one view unfiltered.